# Excel incorrect parsel: getting date instead of float in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a high number of Excel files that I have to concat. When I concat them, following this code below, it seems that one of the columns is being read as Datetime by Pandas.

```
path = ["/content/drive/MyDrive/Data REE/XLSX - GENERACIÓN","/content/drive/MyDrive/Data REE/XLSX - EMISIONES"]
lista = [1,2]
for i in range(2):
  lista[i] = pd.concat(map(pd.read_excel, glob.glob(path[i] + "/*.xlsx")))
```

This is the output that I am getting after concatenating the file:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-08-01','2021-08-02','2021-08-03','2021-08-04'],'Wind Energy':[0,0,0,0],'Charcoal':[122,125,128,130], 'Gas':['2021-04-05','2021-04-05','2021-04-05','2021-04-05']})
df
```

I have checked some of the Excel files and it seems there is an error parse. All columns that have a float value (4.5 or 6.7, for example), Excel is reading them as a date. You only can see this if you click over the cell. That's the reason Pandas is reading it as a date.

Also, when I try to modify the format cell in Excel to number, the date is changed to a big big number that makes non-sense with the original value. I think the error is related to using a point instead of a comma to separate the decimal part of the number.

[image]

My doubt is if there is any way to parse this correctly in Pandas without open all the Excel files one by one changing this. Do you know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to import the file as excel (xlsx) or csv file? AND did you try to open the data and edit the column data type manually? I had the same problem and checking these two helped me.

Comment: Try adding pd.read_excel('***.xlsx', dtype={'Gas': float})

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but I am using the Glob library. When I add the dtype={'Gas': float} inside the pd.read_excel, it is not working. The error says: read_excel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'io'.

Comment: I am trying to import them as excel, as you can see in the code. I can do this manually, but I have 365 files, which it's a high number. If I try to change the column data type in Pandas, it returns the datetime directly. Thanks!